# curl (7): Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle

Hello I am testing the endpoint and when I run php testing.php I get this error. Any help would be appreciated it.

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException' with         message '[curl] 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused [url] http://localhost:8000/api/programmers' guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti.php:359 ...`

I've tried 127.0.0.1 as well and it didnt work

here is testing.php

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Guzzle\Http\Client;

// create our http client (Guzzle)
$client = new Client('http://localhost:8000', array(
    'request.options' => array(
        'exceptions' => false,
    )
));

$nickname = 'ObjectOrienter'.rand(0, 999);
$data = array(
    'nickname' => $nickname,
    'avatarNumber' => 5,
    'tagLine' => 'a test dev!'
);

$request = $client->post('/api/programmers', null, json_encode($data));
$response = $request->send();

echo $response;
echo "\n\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using linux, make sure the server is running using

```
/etc/init.d/httpd status
```

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same, when http://localhost:8000 or http://127.0.0.1:8000 neither worked. I solved it using my network IP like

```
192.168.0.3:8000
```

Comment: Is it a matter of public/private network? The curl doesn't have permission to send request in private network?

Comment: Yes, It seems so

Comment: I realised that localhost:8000 wasn't working was because I was using Docker containers, and internally they wouldn't see each other as localhost, but as their specific local IP address (e.g. 172..).

Comment: failed to connect to localhost:9150

Answer (score 1):

If you are running localhost like so:

php -S localhost:8000

and then running curl from a different environment like vagrant then localhost on your vagrant is not the same as localhost on your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your localhost:8000 server is running. 
If it is not then start it using following command from terminal.
Go to root folder of your project & type,

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t .\public
```

Answer (score -1):

For anybody running into this issue when running Wordpress with `wp-env start` on Windows or Mac, Docker Desktop provides a special DNS name `host.docker.internal`, which you can use to refer to the host machine from within a Docker container. If this is your case, then you should be able to fix the issue by simply replacing `localhost` with `host.docker.internal`.

Comment: "This issue seems to occur whenever WordPress is being run locally within a Docker container." - how did you guess that? The OP didn't write anything about using Docker or Wordpress

Comment: @NicoHaase I believe it is common practice to run WordPress locally with `wp-env start`, which in turn uses Docker.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. What makes you think that the original problem is related to Wordpress? The code shared by Ris does not look like Wordpress code

Comment: You're right, thank you for the heads up. I believe it is clearer now.